# Reuse the django form request

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a page that displays a report according to the informed criteria, within that same page I would like to create a "send by email" button, how could I do to take advantage of the same request?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate function that handles a `POST` request and then in your form bind the `action` attribute to that function, for example:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('handle_second_form/', views.handle_second_form, name="handle_second_form"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def handle_second_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'data': data})
```

Then in your template add a second form like this:

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'handle_second_form %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Enter your data">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm very happy for your answer but I didn't understand how I can use the object shown in the listing in a new method, when I tried to use the syntax "data = request.POST.get ('my_data')" the object came null.
I search for items and display a list of data, the same data I want to send via email via the "send" button ...

Comment: make sure the data you try to get by value in here `request.POST.get('data')` has the same `name` in your input field, for example here im getting data with `get('data')` in the function and I'm using `name="data"` in my form input field

Comment: request.POST.get ('data') returns None, what I'm not able to do is get the information from the current page to perform the button action in a new method.
"def send_report_renovacoes (request):
      if request.method == 'GET':
          data = request.POST.get ('items') "

Comment: how are you expecting to grab `POST` request data in a `GET` request, you should use `ìf request.method == 'GET'`